# set horizontal ScrollView s height as indexed content height

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a **horizontal** `ScrollView` inside another **vertical**  `Animated.ScrollView`.

I am use the horizontal one as tab-view(snap item changing) and its working perfectly but there is a problem now.... I render different views inside each item of scroll view which has specified heights, `ScrollView` height will get the longest one and all of  tab views get the same height  despite they don't need such a long height:

```
 <Animated.ScrollView>

  <ScrollView    //<<<<<<I'm talk about this one
    ref={(scr) => this._scrollView = scr}
    decelerationRate={0}
    snapToInterval={Dimensions.get('window').width}
    snapToAlignment={"center"}
    pagingEnabled
    horizontal    <<<<<<<<<<
    onContentSizeChange={() => this._scrollView.scrollTo({ x: this.state.index * Dimensions.get('window').width, y: 0, animated: true })}
    onMomentumScrollEnd={(event) => this.focuser(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x)}
   >
    <View>...some thing short<View>
    <View>..some thing Long<View> //<<<<this one is long
    <View>...Some thing short<View>
  </ScrollView>
```

As you see above, the item which I use in second tab has a long height and it stretch the whole height of `ScrollView`! its  no problem now ... its appropriate stretching which I need for this item(this View) but, I don't need such a height for other tab. But they get this height and will able user to Scrolling down. its so ugly. 
I want to set the `height` of `ScrollView` as the height of Current tab content(Current index content ). whats your solution for that ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is a limitation of ScrollView. As a workaround, you might want to try replacing your Views with vertical ScrollViews of fixed size on the page. This way they will all have their individual scrollable height. However, since you're already inside a vertical ScrollView, responding to scrolling events can get a bit tricky.

### Update:

Another approach is to adjust the height of individual items based on their number, so that every page is the same length. You can see it in [this example](https://snack.expo.io/@dols3m/synchronized-scrollviews).

Comment: yes its a bit tricky...can you give me some clue about it?...im very keen to use vertical ScrollView inside another..

Comment: Depending on what you want to accomplish, it might be better to move your tabs to the top level and put animated scrollview inside each tab. If you have nested scrollviews your scroll events inside multiple scrollviews will be registered by the innermost one, if I am not mistaken. The trick can be to disable scrolling in one scrollview and scroll your other view manually with a callback on that event, if needed. Probably not what you need in your situation. It's all I can say without knowing how scrolling should work on your page and what you're using the animated scrollview for.